# Объясните пожалуйста код на C#

Tags: c#, переменные, ввод

Искал то, как в С# ввести сразу несколько переменных в одну строку, так вот, наткнулся на этот код :

```
string t = "";
Console.WriteLine("Введите координаты точки (через пробел):");
t = Console.ReadLine();
string[] tv = t.Split(' ').Where(x => x != "").ToArray(); /*Тут происходит билиберда, которую я не понимаю, особенно зачем нужно Where и что внутри */
int AX = int.Parse(tv[0]);
int AY = int.Parse(tv[1]);
```

И вроде бы все понятно, кроме 4 строки,можете прокомментировать,что в ней происходит, заранее спасибо.
P.S. все работает так то

Comment: И можно ли это сделать как-нибудь проще?К примеру, в C++ можно просто cin>>a>>f;

Comment: если в [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) вторым параметром передать [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) то не будет нужды в `.Where(x => x != "").ToArray()`

Answer (score 4):

Метод Split разделяет строку по пробелам.
В массиве-результате могут быть пустые значения (см. [верхние примеры в разделе Заметки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.100).aspx)).

С помощью [Linq-запроса Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx) выбираются (отфильтровываются) непустые элементы, так что после фильтрации массив `tv` содержит только непустые элементы
(а являются ли они валидными числами - определит уже результат `Parse`)

Comment: @Коновалов Максим Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)